# Minor bug with ViewPager and PhotoViewAttacher

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-viewpager, photo

Minor bug with ViewPager and PhotoViewAttacher, the second and following pictures are displayed at the top first, and only then click the center stand. How to make that picture was in the center?

TestPager.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher;


public class TestPager extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_pager);
    CustomPagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this);
    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Picasso mPicasso;
    PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

    int[] mResources = {
            R.drawable.first,
            R.drawable.second,
            R.drawable.third
    };


    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)       mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item,  container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPager);
         mPicasso.with(TestPager.this).load(mResources[position]).into(imageView);
        container.addView(itemView);
        mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object  object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}

}
```

layout_pager.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

pager_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPager" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used UniversalImageLoader instead of Picasso and met the same problem.
My solution is to **new the attacher in the async loading callback**.

In my case the code is:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(url, imgView, new ImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            // Make imageview interactive
            attacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imgView);
        }
     });
```

For your case using Picasso, it may be like:

```
mPicasso.with(TestPager.this).load(mResources[position]).into(imageView, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView)
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
    }
});
```